# Textsize according to parent button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 HTML buttons.

```
<button class='btn btn-default'>A</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>ABCDEFG</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>B</button>
```

I want a fixed width for every button eg. 38px. When I set css

```
.btn { width: 38px; }
```

it works but the text from the second button overflows. How can I fix this with css? The text should fit in the button not contrary.

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers. I want the text to fit in the button. By fit I mean it should not hide. It should get smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this simply by adding "overflow: hidden" to your btn class. In the snippet below, I included "white-space: nowrap" to force the names to be in one line instead of wrapping and "text-overflow: ellipsis" so that it will add an ellipsis to the end of the label to show there was more. I don't know what you application is, but these are things you can do.

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-default'>A</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>ABCDEFG</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>B</button>
```

Alternatively, if the height can be adjustable, then you can use "word-wrap: break-word" to allow the letters to stack.

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-default'>A</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>ABCDEFG</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>B</button>
```

**Edit**
Since you asked about scaling the fonts based on the button, that can't be done with CSS alone yet (I imagine we'll be able to in the future since we can already [scale widths using the viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)). For now, here's a JavaScript/jQuery snippet I created to do what you need.

```js
$('.btn').each(function() {
  var bw = $(this).width(); //Button's inner width, not including padding
  var tw = $(this).children('span').outerWidth(true); //Text's width
  var c = $(this).text().length; //Number of characters in label
  var cw = tw / c; //Average width of each character
  var max = Math.floor(bw / cw); //Maximum number of characters that can be visible, rounding down to the nearest whole number
  //If there are too many characters, then apply the shrinking formula
  if (c > max) {
    var font = parseFloat($(this).css('font-size'), 10); //Get the CSS font-size as a number (in this case, it should be "16")
    var new_cw = bw / c; //How much average space each character SHOULD take up in the button
    font = font * new_cw / cw;//Typical "proportions" formula to get the scaled font size
    $(this).css('font-size', font + 'px'); //Apply new font size to this button
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.btn span {
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn.big {
  width: 70px;
}

.btn.biggest {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>A</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>AB</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>ABC</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>ABCD</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>ABCDE</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default'><span>ABCDEF</span></button>
<br />
<br />
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCD</span></button>
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCDE</span></button>
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCDEF</span></button>
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCDEFG</span></button>
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGH</span></button>
<button class='btn big btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGHH</span></button>
<br />
<br />
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCD</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDE</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEF</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFG</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGH</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGHH</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGHHH</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGHHHH</span></button>
<button class='btn biggest btn-default'><span>ABCDEFGHHHHH</span></button>
```

In this snippet, I also set different button widths, so this code should be very adaptable for differently sized buttons. When I say the "Typical "proportions" formula" in the comment I am referring to this formula:

[A over B is equal to C over D](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/how-to-solve-linear-equations/ratios-and-proportions-and-how-to-solve-them), where A is the current character width (about 11 in this example), B is the current font size (16 in this example), C is the new character width that fits within the button (calculated as "new_cw"), and we are solving for D, the new font size, by multiplying B and C and dividing by A.

Yay math!

Comment: Is it possible to make the text smaller instead of hiding/wrapping it?

Comment: @Piu130 Not yet with only CSS anyway. I'm sure you can whip something up using JavaScript that can calculate a new font-size based on the button's width. If you have the font-size relative to the viewport (browser's width or mobile screen size), you can use the "vw" unit. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp for more details about the "vw" unit.

Comment: Hey @Piu130 I updated my answer to include a JavaScript/jQuery solution to your problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

add `word-wrap`

```css
button {
  width: 38px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-default'>A</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>ABCDEFG</button>
<button class='btn btn-default'>B</button>
```